Driving a high RPM BLDC efficiently
I'm trying to drive a BLDC at high RPM with low torque requirements. I am getting unexpectedly high current draw (over 6A at what should be 20k RPM) and heating even with no load but the rotor. As this does not change significantly even adding a load, I think the majority of the power is just going into waste heat.
The motor is a 2200 KV D2826 intended for airplane drones.  I'm using a JYQD V6.3 (widely available Chinese board) as a driver. I suspect I'm using the wrong type of driver for what I want to achieve - I don't have experience with BLDC drivers, but my intuition from stepper drivers is that you should be able to control the current you supply independent of speed, and have it work as long as the supplied current is sufficient to move the rotor to the next phase in the corresponding amount of time.
I'd be happy with detailed answers or suggestions on good resources I could read to learn more about this. Everything I turn up searching is unhelpful.

Where is the heating? If it's the FETs, do you have an issue with shoot-through? (i.e: both top and bottom FETs are conducting at once) Remember it's important to consider the on- and off-time characteristics, and these may be improved by driving the gates properly (i.e: draining the gate charge) ... did you write custom firmware, or are you using the supplied firmware?

@Attie: Sorry, I should have clarified that. It's in the motor coils. The FETs are mildly warm but under control with a heat sink. The motor is reaching 75 °C trying to achieve high speeds and I'm shutting it off before it goes past that.

"...you should be able to control the current you supply independent of speed," You can't control the current independent of speed. They are related by a given operating point. Your problem seems to be a poor quality or low-efficiency driver. Or, the driver is not properly "tuned" to the motor.

The motors are made to be light as possible and to a price (like $8 retail).
I suspect they've minimized the copper and permeance to make them cheap and light since they can count on having a lot of cooling air flow in a drone application. There's not much point in a motor that is more efficient if the added weight cancels out the savings in battery mass.
Similar idea to how mains-frequency microwave oven transformers are so small for the power they supply compared to less 'purpose-optimized' designs that are intended for high efficiency 24/7 operation.
Maybe look at 'professional' BLDC motors from the usual industrial suppliers, Portescap, MicroMo etc. If such a motor weighs 500g or 1kg rather than 50g for the same power output it is probably not because one set of engineers is better than the other, more likely it's a different design optimization.
